# Samourai Wallet 0.96.03 APK file

Tags: mobile, samourai-wallet

The [release page](https://github.com/Samourai-Wallet/samourai-wallet-android/releases/tag/0.96.03) for Samourai Wallet 0.96.03 lists an APK hash but does not have a downloadable APK file.

From the available zip or tar.gz files how can I locate (or create) an APK file to compare against the hash listed in GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can only download via the PlayStore for Android 5.0+. However they will have an apk out when they release the 1.0 version and it'll be available on F-Droid.